# centos7 “export: command not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell, java-8, centos7

I have followed a tutorial to install JDK 8 on my computer Centos7 OS, but in the last part I tried to set environment varibles.

In the last part of the tutorial I typed:

```
echo “export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_101” > /etc/profile.d/jre.sh
echo “export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_101/jre” >> /etc/profile.d/jre.sh
echo “export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_101/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_101/jre/bin” >> /etc/profile.d/jre.sh
```

and then I am seeing this when I open the terminal:

```
bash: $'\342\200\234export':order not found
bash: $'\342\200\234export': order not found
bash: $'\342\200\234export': order not found
[evconsul8@localhost ~]$
```

Path:

```
[evconsul8@localhost ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/evconsul8/.local/bin:/home/evconsul8/bin
```

After that I Trying to search the cause open 
~/.bash_profile

```
[root@localhost evconsul8]# gedit ~/.bash_profile
```

Result:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_101
export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_101/jre
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_101/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_101/jre/bin

export PATH
```

Note: In one of my attemps after  the error  I added manually the lines corresponding to JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME and PATH=$PATH in the file above. It was ok??

The principal problem I guess it is causing troubles to other apps in my machine.

Comment: I can’t understand the purpose of this `/etc/profile.d/jre.sh` you are trying to create. According to your posted `.bash_profile`, your environment is already ready to use Java, at least from the `bash`. Besides,these variables `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` are an anachronism anyway. If you have the `bin` folder of your jdk in `PATH`, you can already use all java related tools, they’ll find the needed resources without additional env variables. You even don’t need to change the `PATH`, if you are willing to use the absolute paths to the tools. IDEs like Eclipse work perfectly without any vars…

Comment: That is true, in one of my attemps,  I have written in .bash_profile these lines but it was after the error. The problem is that I did not realize why  these lines appear in the terminal. The fancy quotes ( " ) were the problem. I sorry but I guess that I set-up the env variables twice . I feel some of uncertainty and confusion  about that. Now I am working with Netbeans and I know that I can set JDK  for Netbeans IDE browsing  until this  path /opt/jdk1.8.0_101/bin.

Answer (score 2):

You should use regular double quotes (`"`) to enclose a string and not the fancy ones (`“`) you are using.

Comment: Thanks But I already have  typed this and what it would be the solution?? Maybe should I retype again with double quotes.? In addition  I guess It was not marked an error when  I typed.

Comment: @FernandoPie yup, you should overwrite the places you used the "fancy" quotes.

Comment: I'd even suggest to use single quotes `'` so that $PATH is not expanded at the time of the echo but at the time when the profile is run - depending on what you want

Comment: Ok I have replaced the quotes (") instead these  (“) and rerun commands and the message doesn't appear more.  Thanks.